# Yocto add Shared Library

Tags: shared-libraries, yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe

I am trying to compile this GitHub project I found and add the resulting shared library to my SDK.

The project uses CMake. My recipe can download, and build this project. The resulting binary files work as expected, the given `.so` files contain what I need. When trying to add the `.so` files to my image I get the errors

```
ERROR: dbcppp-1.0+gitrAUTOINC+917c925638-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: -dev package dbcppp-dev contains non-symlink .so '/usr/lib/libdbcppp.so'
-dev package dbcppp-dev contains non-symlink .so '/usr/lib/libxmlmm.so' [dev-elf]
ERROR: dbcppp-1.0+gitrAUTOINC+917c925638-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: dbcppp rdepends on dbcppp-dev [dev-deps]
ERROR: dbcppp-1.0+gitrAUTOINC+917c925638-r0 do_package_qa: QA run found fatal errors. Please consider fixing them.
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/michael/Documents/MAIN_Application/build-fb/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-poky-linux-gnueabi/dbcppp/1.0+gitrAUTOINC+917c925638-r0/temp/log.do_package_qa.10943
ERROR: Task (/home/michael/Documents/MAIN_Application/MAIN_layers/meta-MAINapplication/recipes-core/dbcppp/dbcppp_0.0.bb:do_package_qa) failed with exit code '1'
```

My recipe is as follows:

```
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

SRC_URI = "gitsm://github.com/xR3b0rn/dbcppp.git;protocol=https;branch=master"
        
PV = "1.0+gitr${SRCPV}"
SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

inherit pkgconfig cmake

INSANE_SKIP:${PN} = "ldflags"
INHIBIT_PACKAGE_STRIP = "1"
INHIBIT_SYSROOT_STRIP = "1"
SOLIBS = ".so"
FILES_SOLIBSDEV = ""

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 ${B}/bin/dbcppp ${D}${bindir}
    
     install -d ${D}${libdir}
     install -m 0755 ${B}/src/libdbcppp/libdbcppp.so ${D}${libdir}
     install -m 0755 ${B}/libxmlmm.so ${D}${libdir}
     install -m 0755 ${B}/third-party/libxml2/libxml2.so.2.9.10 ${D}${libdir}          
}

FILES_${PN} += "${libdir}/*"
FILES_${PN}-dev = "${libdir}/* ${includedir}"
```

I have been searching for a while but I cannot find a solution. What do I need to do for this to work?

Edit 1: I updated my bb file to the following. This works but it does not place the necessary header files into my SDK.

```
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

SRC_URI = "gitsm://github.com/xR3b0rn/dbcppp.git;protocol=https;branch=master"
        
PV = "1.0+gitr${SRCPV}"
SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

inherit cmake

INSANE_SKIP:${PN} = "ldflags"
INHIBIT_PACKAGE_STRIP = "1"
INHIBIT_SYSROOT_STRIP = "1"
SOLIBS = ".so"
FILES_SOLIBSDEV = ""

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 ${B}/bin/dbcppp ${D}${bindir}
    
     install -d ${D}${libdir}
     install -m 0755 ${B}/src/libdbcppp/libdbcppp.so ${D}${libdir}
     install -m 0755 ${B}/libxmlmm.so ${D}${libdir}
     install -m 0755 ${B}/third-party/libxml2/libxml2.so ${D}${libdir}          
}

FILES_${PN} += "${libdir}/*.so"
FILES_${PN}-dev = "${includedir}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dbcppp` Cmake file already has an `install` target that installs everything automatically, so you do not need `do_install`.

Try the following recipe:

```bash
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

SRC_URI = "gitsm://github.com/xR3b0rn/dbcppp.git;protocol=https;branch=master"
PV = "1.0+gitr${SRCPV}"
SRCREV = "${AUTOREV}"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

inherit cmake

FILES_${PN} += "/usr/lib/xml2Conf.sh /usr/lib/lib*.so.*"

SOLIBS = ".so"
FILES_SOLIBSDEV = ""
INSANE_SKIP_${PN} += "dev-so"
```

The non-versioned shared libraries `.so` topic is difficult in Yocto, that's why skipping the QA shared library issue is the way to go here if you have no control on the source project's files/libraries.

The above recipe splits into multiple packages:

- `dbcppp` (If you want just the `dbcppp` binary (.so files are shipped for the binary to run)
- `dbcppp-dev` (If you want the header files and the shared libraries)
- `dbcppp-doc` (If you want the man and html pages)

Comment: I am testing this now. Will this also place the necessary header files in usr/include? That was the last issue I found with my bb file above.

Comment: It does place the header files in! I am testing the exported SDK now